# Android Lollipop, Robotium script not working. Getting Service Intent must be explicit act=com.bitbar.testdroid.monitor.ScreenshotService

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, robotium

I just upgraded my phone to Android Lollipop and now my Robotium scripts don't work on it.

It throws the following exception when I call:

```
solo = new ExtSolo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity(), this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), getName());



java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.bitbar.testdroid.monitor.ScreenshotService }
at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:2052)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:2160)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:2138)
at com.bitbar.recorder.extensions.ScreenshotUtils.<init>(ScreenshotUtils.java:50)
at com.bitbar.recorder.extensions.ExtSolo.<init>(ExtSolo.java:152)
at ie.eureka.moveit4.test.activity.SuperTest.setUp(SuperTest.java:176)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1873)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this class "com.bitbar.recorder.extensions.ScreenshotUtils", the com.bitbar.testdroid.monitor.ScreenshotService class is called implicitly. You need now to call explicitly the service by class name and not by filters in your Intent.

Comment: I found that class in one of my jars. I have the latest version recorder-extensions-5.3.jar, surly the guys who developed this jar would release an update for lollipop no?

Comment: Yes sure, they will publish another release compliant Lollipop soon, as it has restricted security aspects

Comment: Can you please elaborate the solution. Am also getting the same error.
Unable to start service Intent { act=com.bitbar.testdroid.monitor.ScreenshotService pkg=com.bitbar.testdroid.monitor } U=0: not found
Provide me complete solution to fix this issue.

Comment: I am having the same problem. There is no way to fix this yourself, as this library is developed by Bitbar/Testdroid. Contact them and ask about an update for Lollipop-compatibility for ExtSolo resp. recorder-extensions-5.3.jar.